# I need to add "Add new item" option in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want to add a button in first element of the list to "Add new item". If user clicks on that button I need to open a pop-up and get the input from users.
How to do this in select2 plugin? Is any default options for this (or) need to customize this?

Comment: I tried below code for select2     https://jsfiddle.net/KpKaran/rqtuk090/

Comment: Another solution: customize noResults with html code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797597/select2-how-to-add-a-link-instead-of-no-results-found-text

Answer (score 19):

Here's my approach

```
$('#select2')
    .select2()
    .on('select2:open', () => {
        $(".select2-results:not(:has(a))").append('<a href="#" style="padding: 6px;height: 20px;display: inline-table;">Create new item</a>');
})
```

[image]

Comment: You can use prepend to add 'Create new item' link in top.

Comment: How to close the `Select` if it's opening a Modal via `data-toggle`?

Answer (score 9):

basically what Kld suggested, but without additional buttons as I understand OP wants to use first option of `select` to trigger new value modal. It checks the value when select2:close event is triggered and if `"NEW"` is selected, prompts for new value, adds at the end of `select` box and selects it.

NOTE: I've disabled search in input and added placeholder

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2")
  .select2({
    placeholder: 'Select type',
    width: '50%',
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
  })
  .on('select2:close', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.val()==="NEW") {
      var newval = prompt("Enter new value: ");
      if(newval !== null) {
        el.append('<option>'+newval+'</option>')
          .val(newval);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySel" class="select2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="NEW">Add new type</option>
  <option>Car</option>
  <option>BUS</option>
  <option>TWO</option>
  <option>THREE</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
  $('#my-select2').select2().on('select2:open', function () {
            var a = $(this).data('select2');
            if (!$('.select2-link').length) {
                a.$results.parents('.select2-results')
                        .append('<div class="select2-link"><a>New item</a></div>')
                        .on('click', function (b) {
                            a.trigger('close');

                            // add your code
                        });
      }
   });
```

[image]

Comment: One side-effect is that it adds a new button for each time the dropdown is opened.

Comment: @TimCadieux you can remove it on select:close event and add it on select:open event to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 6):

HTML Code

```
<div class="input-group">
<select class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-plugin="select2" id='select' tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <optgroup label="Select Cutomer">
    <option value="AK">Zilal</option>
    <option value="HI">Ajay</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrp" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" id="type" class="font-weight-300" data-target="#mdl_Item" data-toggle="modal">+ Add New Vendor</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var flg = 0;

    $('#select').on("select2:open", function () {
      flg++;
      if (flg == 1) {
        $this_html = jQuery('#wrp').html();
        $(".select2-results").append("<div class='select2-results__option'>" + 
      $this_html + "</div>");
      }
    });

});
```

Output looks like as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

May be you should use `tags` options?

https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-options-be-created-based-on-the-search-term

Comment: "click on that button i need to open a pop-up" using tags this is not possible...

Answer (score 3):

After digging around on this subject for quite some time... I *think* I have a solution for this problem.

I noticed that Select2 seems to be creating its own structure within the DOM -- irrespective of the Select that you are interacting with. -- This also appears to be completely independent of the Select you may have created elsewhere in the DOM.

So.... After some fiddling around - I came up with the following code:

**First:** Create a global binding to all Selects in the DOM.  This is only for setting a temporary reference to 'what' the current user is working with -- creating a global variable that can be used later.

```
      $('select').select2().on('select2:open', function() {
                        // set a global reference for the current selected Select
                        console.log('found this ---> '+$(this).attr('id'));
                        if (typeof tempSelectedObj === 'undefined') {
                            tempSelectedObj = null;
                        }
                        tempSelectedObj = this;
                    });
```

**Second:** Create a document 'keyup' event that is mapped to the Select2 temporary INPUT and select2-search__field class. This will capture all key events for the Select2 INPUT.  But in this case, I have added a keyCode === 13 (return character) to init the magic.

```
    $(document).on('keyup','input.select2-search__field',function (e) {
                    // capture the return event
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {

                        var newValue = $(this).val();
                        console.log('processing this: '+newValue);

                        // create new option element
                        var newOpt = $('<option>')
                            .val(newValue)
                            .text(newValue);

                        // append to the current Select
                        $(tempSelectedObj)
                            .append(newOpt);

                        // apply the change and set it
                        $(tempSelectedObj)
                            .val(newValue)
                            .select2('close');
                    }
                })
```

When a return character is detected, the following happens.

- capture the current value
- create a new DOM Option Element (jQuery)
- set the value and text of the new Option Element
- append the new Option Element to the tempSelectedObj variable (jQuery)
- trigger the Select2 to close
- set the value of the Select2 to the new value appended
- trigger the final Select2 change to display the new Option
- DONE!

Obviously the two sections of code are required for this example, but I think it is a pretty slick approach for a problem which a lot of people seem to be struggling with.  And it is generic enough that it could be tailored for other purposes with ease.

Hope this helps!  I have struggled with this for sometime.

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/h690bkmg/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new option to the select2 this way

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var value = prompt("Please enter the new value");
  $(".mySelect")
    .append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value )
    .text(value ));

})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#select2-"+yourelementid+"-container").off().on('click',function(){
                        jQuery("#yourelementid"_add").remove();
                        jQuery("#select2-"+yourelementid+"-results").after("<div id='"+yourelementid+"_add' >optionnameforadding</div> ").promise().done(function(){
                            jQuery("#"+yourelementid+"_add").off().on('click',function(){
                            //  yourfunctionfordisplayingdiv
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

you can add html content after the ul list - select2-"+yourelementid+"-results , and do whatever you can with it. just set the result as the val of the select box

[check the image out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RvFj.png)

Answer (score 2):

A modified version of modped's answer that I used for multi select

```
$('.select2').select2().on('select2:close', function() {
  var el, newOption, newval;
  el = $(this);
  if (el.val() !== null && el.val()[0] === '') {
    el.val(el.val().slice(1));
    el.trigger('change');
    newval = prompt("Enter new value:");
    if (newval !== null && newval !== '') {
      newOption = new Option(newval, newval, true, true);
      return el.append(newOption).trigger('change');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Show Snippet**

```js
$('#select2').select2({
       placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',    
         language: {
             noResults: function() {
            return `<button style="width: 100%" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            onClick='task()'>+ Add New Item</button>
            </li>`;
            }
         },
       
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        }
    });
    
  function task()
  {
  alert("Hello world! ");
  }
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br>
<div class="container">
<select id="select2" style="width: 70%">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="40">Fairy Floss Machine</option>
        <option value="30">Popcorn machine</option>
        <option value="20">Bubble Machine</option>
        <option value="10">Smoke Machine</option>
        <option value="0">party Effect Light</option>
</select>
</div>




<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working for me

```
$('#yourDropdownId').select2({              
              ajax: {
                  url: productUrl, 
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                      search: params.term,
                      page: params.page || 1
                    }

                    // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                    return query;
                  },processResults: function (data, params) {       
                      console.log(data)                                        
                          return {
                              results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                                  return {
                                      text: item.item_name,                        
                                      id: item.item_id
                                  }
                              })
                          };      
                  },    
                  cache: true,
                },language: {
                    noResults: function() {
                        return "<a  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' href='javascript:void();'>Open Model</a>";
                      }
                    },escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                         return markup;
                    }


              });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working example for Select2 v3](https://jsfiddle.net/loginet/1zd50msw/19/) but you can't use the HTML select. Use input instead.

```
<input type="text" class="input_email" name="to_email" id="to_email" />
```

and the JS

```
    $('#to_email').select2({
      placeholder: '',
      allowClear: true,
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
      createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
        //change this to whatever you have to validate
        //I'm returning from ajax a json well formated
        //[
        //  {
        //      id: "0",
        //      text: "No Results Found..."
        //  }
        //]            
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) !== 0;
          }).length === 0) {
          console.log(data);
          return {
            id: term,
            text: term
          };
        }
      },
      ajax: {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/0",
        dataType: "json",
        data: function(term) {
          return {
            term: term,
          };
        },
        results: function(data, term) {
          var results = [];
          $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            results.push({
              id: item.id,
              text: item.title,
            });
            if (item.id == 0) { //no results
              results.length = 0;
            }
          });
          return {
            results: results,
          };
        },
      },
      multiple: true,
    });
```

You have to use **createSearchChoice** if no ajax is need it: From [Select2 docs](https://select2.github.io/select2/)

```
$("#e11_2").select2({
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) { if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} },
    multiple: true,
    data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
});
```